# Create dynamic number of dropboxes with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to be able to have one ViewModel and one View that can create a number of dropboxes

Every dropbox will be a namelist (Same names in all)

Is it possible to have

```
public int NameCount { get; set; }
public List<string> SelectedNames {get;set;}
```

And create the number of dropboxes in NameCount and save the results in SelectedNames ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a custom model binder.